# sql server 2005 clr c# checking file status

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, clr

I need to check the status (existing? or last modified date) of a file on multiple remote windows servers (in LAN). The remote servers need a user name and password to access.

I was trying to do it using T-SQL (sql server 2005), but just thinking it's maybe best to be done using a CLR procedure/function? The reason for using a stored procedure is that this will be used by a ssrs report to show a list of each server has the file (last modified date) or not. The parameter for the procedure/function should be the unc/path of the file on the server.

I knows about CLR, but need the c# code to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you feel that using SQL Server to check the modification date of a remote server is a valid apporach.  I have never heard of of doing this in all my year of programming for nearly 20 years.

Comment: It's to check a file on a server. The reason I have said. The checking result will be showed in a SSRS report. For SSRS to work, it needs to be T-SQL code (stored procedure, function etc). I know SQL Server is not designed to do this but there is CLR on SQL Server, which can use code created by C# and can be deployed in SQL Server as a stored procedure/function. CLR extends the ability of SQL Server. So I am actually asking the c# code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files in question are locatable via UNC path names then this is quite straightforward using c#:

```
var fInfo = new FileInfo("uncPathGoesHere");

if (fInfo.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
{
    //  file modified within last hour
}
```